# Chat application - Notify users with sound when someone enters/leaves the room

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have tweaked the firebase chat app (the one that is available in the quickstart tutor) and added the User status information to it, i.e, when any user enters or leaves the room, a message is displayed to other users. ex: User A has joined.

Now, I am trying to add the sound notification to the app whenever a user leaves or enters the room. I am using `ngAudio` module to do this. But, so far I am not able to achieve this functionality.

Currently, I have tried this.
I am using a shallow watch to keep checking the `chatstatus` array

```
$scope.$watchCollection('chatstatus', function (newVal, oldVal) { 

         if ($scope.chatstatus[$scope.chatstatus.length-1].status.indexOf("joined") > -1) {
            $scope.joinedplay.play();

        }
        else{
            $scope.leftplay.play();
         }

    });
```

But when I do this only the logged in user gets the sound notification but not others (obvious, as the controller is only getting executed for him).

I have also tried using the ngRepeatFinished directive (to trigger the sound notification when the last element of the list is displayed). But that doesn't work too.

I have made a **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xkiVH8WlQGngcfphKqHZ?p=preview)** for this and I exactly want my app to behave as this plunk is behaving.

Open the plunk in two different tabs(OR browsers) and join the chat room with two users. When one of the two users joins/leaves, the other one gets the `alert`. This works as we will be accessing the same plunk.

**But how to achieve this in real time?**

Note: I have used `alert` instead of audio in the above example as it is simpler to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Using `Firebase.on()` solved the problem. 
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html

```
 statusref.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {
            var postsData = null;
            postsData = childSnapshot.val();
            logResults(postsData);
    });

    function logResults(postsData) {
        if (postsData.status.indexOf("joined") > -1) {
            $scope.joinedplay.play();

        }
        else{
            $scope.leftplay.play();
         }
    }
```